# What is the best to select a javascript object property at any depth?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for suggestions on how to select properties on the child level or deeper dynamically.

For example, here is the method that I am currently using. The method parameters is the `object` and either a `string` or `array` for the property name. If a `string` is passed used, it will just will get the property.  The array is iterated through in order to select the property value.

```
getMappedDataProperty: function(obj, map) {
  var m, result, _i, _len;
  if (typeof map === 'string') {
    return obj[map];
  }
  result = obj;
  for (_i = 0, _len = map.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
    m = map[_i];
    result = result[m];
  }
  return result;
}
```

Even though this works, I keep thinking to myself that there has to be a better way of accomplishing this.  Suggestions?

Comment: That is a really roundabout way of doing things.

Comment: [Here's how I've done it in the past](https://gist.github.com/megawac/6162481#file-underscore-lookup-js), however I extended it to convert `'foo.bar[0]' => ['foo', 'bar', '0']`

Comment: @megawac I like the idea of passing in the string 'foo.bar' then splitting it into the array. Might make better sense for the user.

Comment: Looks like you're re-inventing JsonPath.  I did that once for MVC-style property objects.  See http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a once over:

- `getMappedDataProperty` is a clumsy name, how about `getProperty`.
- receiving a string is functionally the same as an array with 1 entry, so you could 
  `map = (typeof map === 'string') ? [map] : map;`
- There is no need for the underscores for `i` and `len`, also, I would rather see `length` than `len`
- the use of the temporary variable `m` is overkill, you could go straight for
   `result = result[map[i]];`

I would counter propose:

```
getProperty: function( o, map ) 
{
  map = (typeof map === 'string') ? [map] : map.slice();
  var result = o;
  while ( map.length ) {
    result = result[ map.shift() ];
  }
  return result;
}
```

I would love to know the context in which you use this, since I cannot see a good use case for it.

Comment: Good point on the name.  Didn't think about the while loop working for just one in the array.  Why do you have the `map.slice()` in the example on the third line?

Comment: I marked as answered, but would still like to see others opinions about this.

Comment: To answer what I am doing: I created a generic filter that will output a flat array of a specific property value of the dataset.  The issue is that some of the properties are at the child level and others at a grandchild level.  Needed to handle getting for both levels.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to suggest on top of @konijn's changes that:

1. You shouldn't clone the `map` as that's just extra overhead as is using shift. I prefer your earlier attempt of just iterating the keys to be honest.
2. You should check if `result[map[i]]` exists before you attempt to access it. So `getProperty({}, ['foo', 'bar'])` won't attempt to access `result['foo'] => undefined['bar']`. As I mentioned in a comment on the OP I've previously implemented this method and I handled this case by returning `undefined` but at the bare minimum you should acknowledge it.
3. I would also suggest you handle numbers in your implementation.

I would suggest an implementation along the lines of:

```
getProperty: function(result, map) {
    var type = typeof map, i = 0, len = map.length;
    if (type === 'string' || type === 'number') return result[map];
    for (; i < len; i++) {
      if(map[i] in result) result = result[map[i]];
      else return undefined;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Later if you decide to handle a map string like `'foo.bar'` it would also be easy to extend this implementation (and it'd start to look even more [like mine](https://gist.github.com/megawac/6162481#file-underscore-lookup-js) lol). All it would take is adapting the string case to `map = map.toString().split('.')`

Comment: +1, I forgot about the fact that the function is very trusting!